# getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/ClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor exception

Tags: struts2

I am getting the exception below in my struts project. I have included xwork-core-2.3.8.jar in the CLASSPATH. I am getting this error when i deploy my application but when i run my application , my action class `com.logging.actions.OperationalSupportAction` is working fine and i am able to display the result back on my screen (jsp page).

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Unable to read class [com.logging.actions.OperationalSupportAction]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/ClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:717)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.<init>(ClassFinder.java:112)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What version of Struts are you using?

Comment: Yes, that's evident from the `xwork` classes, but what _version_?

Comment: did you download struts distro?

Comment: no.. what is struts distro...m new to struts..

Comment: You are most likely either (a) mixing dependency versions, or (b) missing a library. Please add the *precise* libraries you're deploying (e.g., versions) or, if you're using Maven (or an equivalen), post the pom/config for it.

Comment: This are few libraries in my lib folder...struts2-core-2.3.8.jar , struts2-json-plugin-2.3.8.jar , swtgraphics2d.jar, xwork-core-2.3.8.jar, javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar, javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar, asm-3.3.jar, ognl-3.0.6.jar....

Comment: one more thing..i am getting this error but my action class is running fine ...i want know than from where this error is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the struts configuration like `struts.xml` you have written

```
<action class="com.logging.actions.OperationalSupportAction"
```

but there's not such action on the classpath, thus the class reader is unable to get definitions for that class.

Comment: my src folder in included in the .classpath ...and my action class is working fine but when i deploy this project it gives the above  error.

Comment: describe how it's working, I don't see it working at all. edit your question and put details there.

Comment: you should place full stacktrace, including the root cause and full list of jars in the web-inf/lib folder.

Comment: my list of jar files..antlr-2.7.7.jar , asm-3.3.jar , aspectjrt.jar , aspectjweaver.jar , aws-java-sdk-1.3.33.jar , aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.3.33.jar , commons-codec-1.3.jar , 
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar , commons-io-2.0.1.jar , commons-lang-2.4.jar , commons-lang3-3.1.jar , commons-logging-1.1.1.jar , commons-logging-api-1.1.jar , 
dom4j-1.6.1.jar , freemarker-2.3.19.jar , hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar , hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar , hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar , httpclient-4.1.1.jar , httpcore-4.1.jar , iText-2.1.5.jar , javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar

Comment: continue... , javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar , JAXP_146.jar , jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar , 
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar , jcommon-1.0.17.jar , jfreechart-1.0.14.jar , jfreechart-1.0.14-experimental.jar , jfreechart-1.0.14-swt.jar , 
junit.jar , mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar , ognl-3.0.6.jar , servlet.jar , struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.8.jar , struts2-core-2.3.8.jar , struts2-json-plugin-2.3.8.jar , swtgraphics2d.jar , xwork-core-2.3.8.jar

Comment: you've missed aopalliance-1.0.jar,asm-commons-3.3.jar,asm-tree-3.3.jar,classworlds-1.1.jar,commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar,commons-chain-1.2.jar,commons-collections-3.1.jar,commons-digester-2.0.jar,commons-validator-1.3.1.jar,oro-2.0.8.jar.